# IO exception reading json with inputStream

Tags: php, android, json, inputstreamreader

I made a php application at the following url: `http://localhost/index.php/registration/returnItemJson` to return this valid json:

```
{"name":"test","price":30,"description":"is this working"}
```

In my android studio app, I am trying to read it with this:

```
URL url = new URL(strings[0]);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        int response = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("TAG", "Response code "+response);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while(null != (line = reader.readLine())){
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
```

But I am getting an IO exception by connection.GetInputStream().
It works ok when I do this with some other url that returns json, but not with localhost.

Comment: you should use the IP address of your server

Comment: if this is the emulator, localhost resolves to the emulator itself (not your PC). As per @Kidus, use the IP addy.

Comment: yes i use emulator but if i replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 I still get the same error

Comment: @OjamaYellow you can use `10.0.2.2` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `10.0.2.2` instead  to access your local host. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)